# How to I keep a log of urls when a link is clicked?

Tags: php, html

I have a link called "Click Me" on 100 pages on my website. When a person clicks this link, I need to be able to write the url of where the click came from into a txt file or send me an email everytime the link is clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: html form post or ajax post to a php script that does whatever you want

Comment: This is probably already happening in your server access.log

Answer (score 2):

Fragments of code are requested here, please update your question. I will give you an idea on how to acomplish that:

In my opinion the general idea that will work best is:

- Monitor user click with jQuery only if content is Click me.
- When content of click is "Click me" load some php file via Ajax that will monit the click
- Load this file with some parameters (`?referer=`...)
- PHP file will append this `$_GET['referer']` to a txt file

**Remember that user can manually scam Your clicks** (go to php file, and refresh it). You must think of some anti scam filter (for example after clicking lock IP clicks for few seconds or add some random hashes / etc to Your url).

Hope it helps, for more info, please upgrade your question with some code.